# Passing Parameters into POST method in Python

Tags: python, post, parameters, http-post, request-headers

I am trying to create a nameset using the POST method on the given server(url)

I tried several methods to pass the parameters, but I still get the missing parameters' error. Can somebody please help me out?

I am running Python file in cygwin64.

The Code:

```
import requests

import json

URL = "http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/m***/w**/nameset"

payload = {'name':'Test'}     
header = {
    "content-type": "application/json" 
}
# create a nameset
r2 = requests.post(url = URL, auth=('admin', 'admin'), params=payload, headers=header)

print r2.text

print r2.status_code
```

**The error on the terminal:**

```
{"error": {"message": "Missing control \"params\"", "code": 0}}
400
```

Comment: have you tried `data = {'key':'value'}`?

Comment: @Alex , thank for your reply. The "code" is the error code. 

Liora Haydont , thank you for replying! Yes, I have tried that. It results in the same error.